# C#: How to use a non static member to access an object?

Tags: c#, object, select, static

I want to create a basic system for a library of books. I want each book to have a non static int variable called "id". How can i access an object from the class "book" using its variable: "id"? 
by accessing i mean that i want to use the "id" to change other variables or access methods of the object that contains the "id" i gave it. I also don't want to use switch case that checks all declared object's "id" and returns a reference to the object. Instead i want to know if there is a way to find the right object from a list with an unknown size.

---

Here is my code:

```
using System;

class book
{
 public int id;
 public int price;

 public book ( int id, int price )
 {
  this.id = id;
  this.price = price;
 }

 public static book findBook ( int id )
 {
  //what do i put in here?
 }
}

class MainClass
{
 public static void Main( string[] args )
 {
  book b1 = new book( 123, 33 );
  book b2 = new book( 124, 23 );
  book chosenBook;
  int input = Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine() );
  chosenBook = book.findBook( input );
  chosenBook.price = 34;
 }
}
```

---

Comment: What exactly do you want `findBook()` to actually do?  Currently your "known books" aren't actually stored anywhere.  You just have two `book` variables in your `Main()` method.  So if you want to find a book with a given value, you'd have to compare the value to those variables.

Comment: You would need to store the books in an array, list, dictionary, collection or one of many other options. Then you need to search - this can be done in a for loop, or using LINQ, or one of many other ways. Really your question has many, many solutions & you need to do a bit of research into C# to find some of the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an object that manages your books, an Array, List, or any other Collection. Like for example:

```
            book b1 = new book(123, 33);
            book b2 = new book(124, 23);
            var books = new List<book>() { b1, b2 };
            book chosenBook;
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            chosenBook = books.FirstOrDefault(b => b.id == input);
            chosenBook.price = 34;
```

or:

```
class book
{
    public int id;
    public int price;

    public book(int id, int price)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public static List<book> currentBooks { get; set; } = new List<book>();

    public static book findBook(int id)
    {
        return currentBooks.FirstOrDefault(b => b.id == id);
    }
}

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            book b1 = new book(123, 33);
            book b2 = new book(124, 23);
            book.currentBooks.Add(b1);
            book.currentBooks.Add(b2);
            book chosenBook;
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            chosenBook = book.findBook(input);
            chosenBook.price = 34;
        }
    }
```

or:

```
    class book
    {
        public int id;
        public int price;

        public book(int id, int price)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public static Dictionary<int, book> currentBooks { get; set; } = new Dictionary<int, book>();

        public static book findBook(int id)
        {
   book result = null;
            currentBooks .TryGetValue(id, out result);
return result;
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            book b1 = new book(123, 33);
            book b2 = new book(124, 23);
            book.currentBooks.Add(b1.id, b1);
            book.currentBooks.Add(b2.id, b2);
            book chosenBook;
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            chosenBook = book.findBook(input);
            chosenBook.price = 34;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For a small collection of books this would be OK - but for a large collection it may be unacceptably slow. LINQ can be a lot slower than a for or foreach loop. There would be big advantages to using a Dictionary (or similar) with the id as key.

Comment: _"public static book findBook(int id) { book fndBook; currentBooks.TryGetValue(id, out fndBook); return fndBook; }"_ may be better, if the book is not in the Dictionary then fndBook will be set to null. In your solution two searches are required to return the reference - probably not too much of a performance impact though.